# @Embeddedid, @Embeddable equivalent to C#

Tags: java, c#, entity-framework, jpa

In java we can make a class as a key for an entity. This can be possible by using the annotation @EmbeddedId in id class property, and in the class use the annotation @Embeddable. But in c#, I did'nt find anything similar. Theres a trick to solve this issue? Thanks all!

Comment: By default, anything with `Id` or `<type name>Id` is treated as the primary key in EF. You can also use `[Key]` attribute to decorate the property. See [Keys (primary)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys).

Comment: When I try to create an entity with a custom key, EF throw the followeing exception: `...because the property type is not a valid key type. Only scalar types, string and byte[] are supported key types.`

Comment: What is the type of the key? Can you update your question with the model class?

Comment: I tried with a class and struct, with the annotations contained in `Guid` struct, but give me the same error.

Comment: Please update your question with the model you are having trouble with, it is difficult to tell what your code looks like from a description of what you are doing.